# Hypergeometric test for enrichment analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, p-value, biostatistics, hypergeometric-distribution

I am referring to a **[previously asked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290893/modify-hypergeometric-test/290920?noredirect=1#comment555236_290920)** on my case for gene enrichment analysis using hypergeometric distribution. Here is my modified question (many thanks to @Glen_b):

I have a mixture of **1496** genes (population size) which **150** (successes in population) of them are tumor suppressors (TS). I have a presumed algorithm which claims it has the ability to select genes with a cancerous behavior (i.e. it draws as many oncogenes (OG) as possible with the fewest number of TS). So, this algorithm draws **757** genes (sample size) containing **69** TS (successes in sample). To examine whether this algorithm is *really* behaves highly selective or just selects by chance, I intend to calculate one-tailed hypergeoemtric p-value, as follows:

```
                 Succ  Fail  Total
   Population:   150   1346   1496
   Sampled:      69    688    757
   Remaining:    81    658    739
```

I use this [website](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573201) for this purpose, and the results would be:

```
hypergeometric               value
distribution    

probability mass f          0.0339
lower cumulative P          0.135
upper cumulative Q          0.899
mean                        75.90
```

Since other similar studies report *upper cumulative Q*, I am also focusing on that. As apparent the p-value is insignificant; however, as mentioned above, fewer number of success in sample size denotes the higher predictive power of the algorithm. Therefore, the algorithm in fact acts pretty good. In such a case, how can I modify my problem to get a significant p-value regarding this fact that in this case, enrichment means *fewer* and not *more* genes in the sample drawn.

Comment: You should make your null and alternative clear (especially if this is still a one tailed test). I would add that there's really very little evidence for the claim that this is "highly selective"; the chances of getting 69 or fewer successes purely by chance (i.e. if the process is effectively random, not selective, which is 0.135) is pretty high -- I don't see any basis for asserting that anything "selective" is going on at all. It's not clear to me why you're looking at the "upper" figure since the 0.135 is the correct p-value for the alternative hypothesis that you select better than random

Comment: (I completely agree with the 0.135 figure you have there -- I get the same value for a one tailed test)

Comment: If you resolved the issue with the first set of numbers it might be worth commenting under the Q or adding an update to the Q to clarify how that happened; if it was something other than a simple error it might still tell us something useful that is not otherwise clear in either question.

Comment: @ Glen_b: I think I should use _lower cumulative P_ here, because I am intend to test the probability of 69 or less (especially in my case where fewer number of successes is the goal), am I right? I pointed out to the upper cumulative Q, because it is reported when dealing with oncogenes (clearly higher is better). Of course the algorithm is not selective, but this is just a sample output. I just wanted to figure out which p-value I should report and use. Therefore, if I am getting this right, 0.135 is the one I need. Am I correct? Best

Comment: In words the null would be something like "$H_0$: The probability of selecting TS genes is no lower than random selection from the population" and the alternative, "$H_1$: The probability of selecting TS genes is lower than random selection from the population". That seems to correspond to what you discussed (though it could be rephrased into being about OG and then it would be "no higher" in H0 and "higher" in H1 (and then you *would* use an upper tail value). If this null and alternative are correct then the right p-value is indeed 0.135

Comment: If you redo it in terms of OG, and use the upper tail you will get p=0.135 again.

Comment: I don't know if this is really answering your question though. If it is I can paste it into an answer.

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't address how to get a significant p-value... if that's the data, that's the data. If the effect was real but small like this (10% in the population but 9.1% in your sample), your sample size was too small to reliably pick it up as being inconsistent with just selecting by chance. You could treat this as a pilot I guess (you already looked at it) and use it as the basis for a power study to work out how big a sample you'd need, but in many cases that's simply not feasible, in which case, 0.135 is it.

Comment: (Do people in your area do power calculations before collecting the data? I can't say I've heard of it, but I don't read a lot about gene studies)

Comment: @Glen_b: In fact, the algorithm here is a method that can extract a  subnetwork from a generic network (i.e. network consisting of all known human genes in terms of metabolic studies). So, one of the methods to examine the algorithm predictive power (i.e. its ability to extract a cancer-specific network), is using the set of universally available OG or TS. So, here I assumed that all genes in my generic network is population, all TS in this network are successes; number of genes in the extracted network are sample size (which is determined by algorithmic approach), and TS in the ...cnt

Comment: cnt...extracted cancer network are successes in the sample. Thus, hypergeometric p-value seems one possible way to examine the ability of algorithm to extract a _context-specific_ behavior. Hence, I could deduce that _lower cumulative P_ is the one I should follow. Also, regarding the small size of the population, I should point out that the population size and number of successes are _constant_ here (as I mentioned, those come from generic human network); however, algorithm can act differently as the result of other input data, so sample size and number of successes in sample can vary...cnt

Comment: cnt...I don't know how to thank you for your detailed explain and of course, patience over my ignorance of the field. Best regards.